# How exactly is "input rate" calculated in IOS "sh int" output?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, interface

Cisco IOS routers display input and output *bps* and *pps* values for `load-interval` time period in `sh int` output. For example here is `load-interval` set to 30 seconds:

```
C1921#sh int Gi0/1 | i rate 
  30 second input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  30 second output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
C1921#
```

Am I correct that "input rate" is simply an average value of `packets input`(for *pps*) and `bytes`(for *bps*) counters for `load-interval` period of time? Both `packets input` and `bytes` counters are seen in `sh int` output.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the average input and output rates, seen by the interface (in the last 30 seconds, for your example). The `load-interval <seconds>` command will let you change the time period, but I believe that 30 seconds is the shortest time period accepted.

You are incorrect about it being bytes. It is bits per second (bps). Bytes per second is Bps (upper-case `B`), but bits per second is bps (lower-case `b`). That interface is a 1 Gbps (1,000,000,000 bps) interface. If that interface sent the maximum bps for one second during the 30 second interval, and nothing else, you would see `33,333,333` as the output rate. Basically, you take the number of bits transferred in a direction (input or output) and divide it by the `load-interval` number of seconds to arrive at the `bits/sec` rate for that direction. The same thing happens for packets.